# Modal hide is not working in ruby on rails 3.2.21 using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I wanted to submit a form through ajax. After rendering new.js.erb it is not going to create.js.erb, though create controller is being called. All the code in create.js.erb is somehow being skipped. Thus neither my modal is closing nor it is rendering any pages.

This is my modal file:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">  
  <div class="modal-content">

<h3> New Article </h3>

<%= form_for @article, remote: true , html: {style: "display:inline;"} do |f| %>
  <div class ="modal-body">
  <div class="field form-group">
  <ul class="errors"></ul>

    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title ,class: 'form-control'%>
  </div>
 
  <div class="field form-group">
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :text ,class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  </div>
 
<div class="modal-footer">
  
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", "#", class: "btn", data: {dismiss: "modal"} %>

</div>
<% end %>

</div>
</div>
```

File new.js.erb:

```html
$("#article-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'new') %>")
$("#article-modal").modal("show")
```

File create.js.erb

```
<%= render "save" %>
```

File save.js.erb:

```html
$("ul.errors").html("")
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
 <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
 $("ul.errors").append($("<li />").html("<%= message.html_safe %>"))
 <% end %>
<% else %>
 $(".article-index").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index')%>")
 $("#article-modal").modal("hide")
<% end %>
```

I am fairly new in Ruby.Please help.

This is being displayed in console :

```html
Started GET "/articles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 17:13:48 +0530
Processing by ArticlesController#new as JS
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered articles/_newedit.html.erb (9.5ms)
  Rendered articles/_new.html.erb (10.6ms)
  Rendered articles/new.js.erb (11.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17.0ms (Views: 14.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Solr: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 17:13:58 +0530
Processing by ArticlesController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NfHEpBGzNdP0DBxhKpw4QH5QGK+dheQAwVDpCxruZVw=", "article"=>{"title"=>"Rohit", "text"=>"asdf"}, "commit"=>"Create Article"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" 
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "articles" ("created_at", "text", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 18 Feb 2016 11:43:58 UTC +00:00], ["text", "asdf"], ["title", "Rohit"], ["updated_at", Thu, 18 Feb 2016 11:43:58 UTC +00:00]]
  SOLR Request (12.3ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f89fc963808> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">Article 60</field><field name="type">Article</field><field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name="class_name">Article</field><field name="text_text">asdf</field><field name="title_text">Rohit</field></doc></add>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
   (90.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/60
  SOLR Request (259.9ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x007f89fc963808> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><commit/>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
Completed 302 Found in 406.3ms (ActiveRecord: 93.1ms)


Started GET "/articles/60" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-18 17:13:58 +0530
Processing by ArticlesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"60"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "60"]]
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 35.1ms (Views: 32.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Solr: 272.2ms)
```

Comment: Look in your log file: it will show you which action is being called and any files which are being rendered.  Put extra logging into your controller to see what's happening, if needed.

Comment: when I click on submit... modal does not hide, but if i click on back then reload it appears in index, so I am assuming it is not going to _save.js.erb ... I am adding my log in question.....

Comment: Have you tried `alert('Hello')` in `show.js.erb` to test the `JS` call?